# Разбиение частей массива на переменные

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Здравствуйте.
 На данном этапе задача такова:
 Я получаю ячейку из базы, содержание которой:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"3"},
{"id":"2","value":"2"},
{"id":"3","value":"2"},
{"id":"4","value":"3"},
{"id":"13","value":""},
{"id":"14","value":""},
{"id":"15","value":""},
{"id":"16","value":""},
{"id":"17","value":""},
{"id":"18","value":""},
{"id":"19","value":"\u041e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 3 \u043c\u0435\u0441\u044f\u0446\u0435\u0432"},
{"id":"20","value":"\u041e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 2 \u043d\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043b\u044c"},
{"id":"21","value":""},
{"id":"22","value":""},
{"id":"27","value":"\/images\/I9vh0kE3vkk.jpg"},
{"id":"28","value":"123"},
{"id":"29","value":"456"}]
```

Получаю я ее следующим образом:

```
$e=mysql_query ('SELECT поле FROM таблица  WHERE  id=123');
while ($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($e))
{
$json = $rowe['extra_fields'];

$arr = json_decode($json, true);    
print_r(array_slice($arr, -2, 2, true));
}
```

Вот результат:

```
(
[15] => Array
(
[id] => 28
[value] => 123
)

[16] => Array
(
[id] => 29
[value] => 456
)
)
```

Далее мне нужно, чтобы я мог вывести отдельно элемент массива (value), у которого [id] => 28 и [id] => 29.
 Заранее спасибо )

Comment: текст вашего вопроса имеет смысл со слов "вот результат". можете удалить все предшествующее, оно не имеет значения. В чем конкретно у вас возникает проблема, или что вы не понимаете?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы я мог вывести отдельно элемент массива (value), у которого [id] => 28 и [id] => 29.

Comment: это я понял. в чем возникает проблема у вас при решении этой задачи?

Comment: В том, что я не знаю как это сделать :)

Comment: `list($a, $b) = array_values(array_slice(....))` и потом `$a['value']` и `$b['value]` вас устроит? или каким то другим способом надо получить?

Comment: отлично! все получилось.  
а как можно получать из массива такой структуры value через id ? 
 Например: `[16] => Array
(
[id] => 29
[value] => 456
)`
  мне нужно из всей ячейки выбрать value от элемента с [id] => 29 ?

Comment: пройтись циклом по массиву, найти где id = 29, и вывести value

Comment: Можете подсказать как это сделать? у меня сейчас получилась такая штука: `$e=mysql_query ('SELECT extra_fields FROM d34mhcopy_k2_items  WHERE  id='.$row->id.'');
while ($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($e))  {
$json = $rowe['extra_fields'];
$arr = json_decode($json, true); 
list($a, $b) = array_values(array_slice($arr, -2, 2, true));
echo '<div class="portceni">'.$a['value'].'<br>';
echo $b['value'].'</div>';` http://prntscr.com/ewxbdt